# Double/long support for JTokenTypes?

Tags: c#, json.net

Is there a way to designate that the Type of a `JToken` is of type `double` or `long`? I noticed that only `integer`s and `float`s are supported via https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JTokenType.cs and wonder how people handle the higher precision cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JSON doesn't distinguish between `double` and `float`. It doesn't even really distinguish between integers and non-integers - they're just numbers.

But `JsonTokenType.Float` isn't really meant to indicate `System.Single` - it's "a floating point number". Likewise `JsonTokenType.Integer` isn't meant to indicate `System.Int32` - it's "an integer".

For examples of this, look at [`JValue`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Linq/JValue.cs):

- The constructor accepting `long` sets the token type to `Integer`
- The constructor accepting `double` sets the token type to `Float`
- The constructor accepting `decimal` sets the token type to `Float`